# Remote SpamAssassin network protocol (spamc) returns empty response

Tags: php, sockets, ubuntu, fopen, spamassassin

I am using [a basic PHP class](https://github.com/webeith/php-spamassassin) to run the [SpamAssassin Network Protocol](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin/trunk/spamd/PROTOCOL) commands on a remote server. I installed SpamAssassin [following a guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-spamassassin-on-ubuntu-12-04), just skipping the PostFix part.

No matter what command I run (`CHECK`, `REPORT`, `PING`, etc), I only get a blank or empty response.

Here is a basic example of a PING that should return, per the manual: `SPAMD/1.5 0 PONG\r\n`. Instead, it's an empty response.

```
$socket = fsockopen($hostname = 'my-remote-server-ip', $port = 783, $errno, $errstr);
fwrite($socket, "PING SPAMC/1.5\r\n");
$response = fread($socket,99999);
die("<pre>" . print_r($response,1) . "</pre>");
```

Am I doing something wrong with my writing/reading? What settings should I be checking on my remote server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my remote connection was being refused. I figured this out by running `spamd -D -i my.remote.ip -p 783`, which actively shows you the debugging information for spamd.

This log showed me
`warn: spamd: unauthorized connection from my.full.local.addr [my.local.ip] at port 54006 at /usr/sbin/spamd line 1271.`

I needed to explicitly allow my local IP using `-A`. 
So, I need to start up spamd from the command line on my remote server with `spamd -D -i my.remote.ip -p 783 -A my.local.ip`.

Running my example now shows a `warn: spamd: bad protocol: header error: (EOF during headers)` error, because of how I'm opening the socket in my simple example. If I use the [GitHub repo I linked](https://github.com/webeith/php-spamassassin), it now returns correctly.